# Match a single character without closing string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, pcre

I am trying to match some URL patterns using PCRE regex in my .htaccess file. This is my current regex:

`investor-advice/glossary/(?:[a-z]|all)(/P[0-9]+)?`

I'd like to limit the `[a-z]` characters to a single character and I have tried numerous things to make this work without success.

The only thing that seems to work is closing off the string after `[a-z]` like so:

`investor-advice/glossary/(?:[a-z]$|all)(/P[0-9]+)?`

However closing the string at this point means that I can't match the `(/P[0-9]+)` segment that follows. Is there another way to achieve this?

I have also tried `[a-z]{1}` to no avail.

Comment: Try `investor-advice/glossary/(?:all|[a-z])(/P[0-9]+)?$`. This way, you will match `investor-advice/glossary/all`, `investor-advice/glossary/all/P12` or `investor-advice/glossary/d`, `investor-advice/glossary/t/P13`.

Comment: That worked! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
investor-advice/glossary/(?:all|[a-z])(/P[0-9]+)?$
```

The main point is that the end of string anchor `$` is moved to the end of the pattern to only allow paths like `investor-advice/glossary/all`, `investor-advice/glossary/all/P12`, `investor-advice/glossary/d` or `investor-advice/glossary/t/P13`.